# Add unique keys for items in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the next application:
https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-murdock-87j13?file=/SubForm.js

```js
 <Form.List name="names">
        {(fields, { add, remove }) => {
          return (
            <div>
              {fields.map((field, index) => {
                console.log("m", field);
                return (
                  <Form.Item
                    {...(index === 0
                      ? formItemLayout
                      : formItemLayoutWithOutLabel)}
                    label={index === 0 ? "Passengers" : ""}
                    required={false}
                    key={index}
                  >
                    <Form.Item
                      {...field}
                      name={[field.name, "outer"]}
                      fieldKey={[field.fieldKey, "outer"]}
                      validateTrigger={["onChange", "onBlur"]}
                      rules={[
                        {
                          required: true,
                          whitespace: true,
                          message:
                            "Please input passenger's name or delete this field."
                        }
                      ]}
                      noStyle
                    >
                      <Input
                        placeholder="passenger name"
                        style={{ width: "60%" }}
                      />
                    </Form.Item>
                    <Form.Item
                      {...field}
                      name={[field.name, "outer1"]}
                      fieldKey={[field.fieldKey, "outer1"]}
                      validateTrigger={["onChange", "onBlur"]}
                      rules={[
                        {
                          required: true,
                          whitespace: true,
                          message:
                            "Please input passenger's name or delete this field."
                        }
                      ]}
                      noStyle
                    >
                      <Input
                        placeholder="passenger name"
                        style={{ width: "60%" }}
                      />
                    </Form.Item>
                    <Form.Item>
                      <InnerForm fieldKey={field.key} />
                    </Form.Item>
                    {fields.length > 1 ? (
                      <MinusCircleOutlined
                        className="dynamic-delete-button"
                        style={{ margin: "0 8px" }}
                        onClick={() => {
                          remove(field.name);
                        }}
                      />
                    ) : null}
                  </Form.Item>
                );
              })}
              <Form.Item>
                <Button
                  type="dashed"
                  onClick={() => {
                    add();
                  }}
                  style={{ width: "60%" }}
                >
                  <PlusOutlined /> Add field
                </Button>
              </Form.Item>
            </div>
          );
        }}
      </Form.List>

      <Form.Item>
        <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">
          Submit
        </Button>
      </Form.Item>
    </Form>
```

When user click on `Add field` button, in console appears the warning:

```css
Warning: Encountered two children with the same key, `0`. Keys should be unique so that components maintain their identity across updates. Non-unique keys may cause children to be duplicated and/or omitted — the behavior is unsupported and could change in a future version.
```

Also this warning appears when i click on `Add sub-field`. I can't figure out why this warning appears.

 Question: Why the above warning appears and how to remove it?

Comment: Keys help React identity which items have changed (added/removed/re-ordered). To give a unique identity to every element inside the array, a key is required. So you need to add a unique key for all of the react element rendering in the page. The system should be ```key={keyName}```

Comment: @MANISHKUMARCHOUDHARY, but now all items have keys, where could be the problem?

Comment: ```console.log(index)``` I think the two keys have same value. We should avoid component with a duplicate key too. The problem should be inside the ```map(..) ```function where the key value is getting mapped

Comment: @MANISHKUMARCHOUDHARY, inside `map()` every item has `key={index}`. Why the warning could appear?

Comment: because the index value will be the same for both the ```<Form.Item>``` right?

Comment: @MANISHKUMARCHOUDHARY, probably yes, but how can i add different indexes for each each <Form.Item>?

Comment: the easiest thing that you can do it to add ```key={"innerName"}``` for the first element and second element use ```key={"innerName2"}```  I have just used your naming only. Please give it a try

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217145/discussion-between-asking-and-manish-kumar-choudhary).

Comment: @MANISHKUMARCHOUDHARY, https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-murdock-87j13?file=/index.js, 
I added  but now if click 2 times on `Add field button`, the warning also appears even i added indexes. Where do you think that i should add another index?
Because i added everywhere

Answer (score 2):

You have two `Form.Item` Component in your code, and they use same key `index`, try to use different key like `'item1' + index` and `'item2' + index`.

And, in your index.js file also have same problem.

Here is Demo forked from you: https://codesandbox.io/s/dark-darkness-xz0wf?file=/SubForm.js

Answer (score 0):

As reactJs primary works on re rendering items every time you make a change the state of that component. It requires an unique key to track each and every item so that re-rendering can be optimized. Not all items needs to be re-render every time.

This warning essentially means that you have multiple items with same key names. In order to fix this you have to provide unique "key" attribute to each child component which is getting updated, components which can potentially trigger an re-render.

Comment: ,i checked my code and now all elements have keys, but i can't figure out  how to change the code to make disappearing the warning, could you help please?

Comment: one request first : passing index as key value is an anti-pattern it can cause a lot of problem. Could you please pass some unique values to key instead of 'index' and again check once.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to use multiple times key={index} or  key={"g"}
use once only.

Please try following

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
import './index.css';
import { Form, Input, Button, Space } from 'antd';
import { MinusCircleOutlined, PlusOutlined } from '@ant-design/icons';

const Demo = () => {
  const onFinish = values => {
    console.log('Received values of form:', values);
  };

  return (
    <Form name="dynamic_form_nest_item" onFinish={onFinish} autoComplete="off">
      <Form.List name="users">
        {(fields, { add, remove }) => {
          return (
            <div>
              {fields.map(field => (
                <Space key={field.key} style={{ display: 'flex', marginBottom: 8 }} align="start">
                  <Form.Item
                    {...field}
                    name={[field.name, 'innerName']}
                    fieldKey={[field.fieldKey, 'innerName']}
                    
                  >
                    <Input placeholder="passenger 1" />
                  </Form.Item>
                  <Form.Item
                    {...field}
                    name={[field.name, 'innerName2']}
                    fieldKey={[field.fieldKey, 'innerName2']}
                  >
                    <Input placeholder="passenger 2" />
                  </Form.Item>

                  <MinusCircleOutlined
                    onClick={() => {
                      remove(field.name);
                    }}
                  />
                </Space>
              ))}

              <Form.Item>
                <Button
                  type="dashed"
                  onClick={() => {
                    add();
                  }}
                  block
                >
                  <PlusOutlined /> Add field
                </Button>
              </Form.Item>
            </div>
          );
        }}
      </Form.List>

      <Form.Item>
        <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">
          Submit
        </Button>
      </Form.Item>
    </Form>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<Demo />, document.getElementById('container'));
```